# What are the different Status options for Dell show copper-ports command?

Tags: port, switch, dell, testing

When the below command is issued in a Dell N2024P/N3024F switch

```
show copper-ports tdr
```

The following output is generated

```
Port     Result      Length   Date
Gi1/0/1  OK          0 - 10   Jan 1 00:00:01 2015
Gi1/0/2  Cross Talk  0 - 10   Jan 1 00:00:01 2015
Gi1/0/3  No Cable    0 - 10   Jan 1 00:00:01 2015
Gi1/0/4  Open        0 - 10   Jan 1 00:00:01 2015
Gi1/0/4  Short       0 - 10   Jan 1 00:00:01 2015
```

However, I am having a very hard time locating an exhaustive list of `Result` output possibilities. Can someone tell me how many there are, and a quick description of what each one means.

Comment: This information should be in the Help manual/system. Have you looked there?

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is a problem because it is nowhere in the help or documentation of the DELL switches (as so much more is not).

But, regarding to a post in the DELL Support community (I am unable to find the link right now but will update as soon as I found it), the possible results are:

```
    No Cable — There is not a cable connected to the port.

    Open Cable — The cable is open (nothing on the end).

    Short Cable — A short has occurred in the cable.

    OK — The cable passed the test.

    Fiber Cable — A fiber cable is connected to the port. 

    Cross Talk — NEXT detected on the cable

    Test as not been performed — The test could not been performed for some reason
```

Hope, this helps. Regards